# Image attribute not properly formatted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, dropzone.js

I m trying to append image attributes into the my div image container but as i can see, the image is not in the same container

```
<img id="imgUpload" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;" class="img-thumbnail"></img>
<img src="static/uploads/4178ba43-a9f1-4315-b8ea-88c0531cc042.png"><img id="imgUpload" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;" class="img-thumbnail"></img>
```

Here is the following script.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: 'upload',
            dataType: 'json',
            add: function (e, data) {
                data.submit();
            },
            success:function(response,status) {
                console.log(response.filename);
                var filePath = 'static/uploads/' + response.filename;
                $("#imgUpload").append($("<img>", { src: filePath }));
                $('#filePath').val(filePath);
                console.log('success');
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Here is the following html elements which supposed to play that role.

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <img id="imgUpload" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;" class="img-thumbnail"/><input type="hidden" name="filePath" id="filePath"></input>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `$("#imgUpload").append($("<img>", { src: filePath }));` should be `$("#imgUpload").attr('src',filePath);`

Comment: appending img within a img ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thumbnail, only one image displays instead of all,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287857/thumbnail-only-one-image-displays-instead-of-all)

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line

```
$("#imgUpload").append($("<img>", { src: filePath }));
```

To

```
$("#imgUpload").attr("src", filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, the code was initally on `.attr` and it shows only one thumbnail. I want to display all the thumbs

Answer (score 1):

I went through your previous question

I think you need this

```
var img = $('<img />', { 

  src: filePath

});
img.appendTo($('.pull-right'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You use **Attr** like this 
`$("#imgUpload").append($("<img>", { src: filePath }));` to `$("#imgUpload").attr("src", filePath);`

this Example

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'upload',
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.submit();
        },
        success:function(response,status) {
            console.log(response.filename);
            var filePath = 'static/uploads/' + response.filename;
            $("#imgUpload").attr("src", filePath);
            $('#filePath').val(filePath);
            console.log('success');
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: this displays only one thumbnail, i want it display all uploaded images.

Comment: what values comes this "response.filename"  or console.log(response.filename);

Comment: `dc9fe2ff-2e3c-47a7-aefd-6d72a29c3702.png
files:46 success
files:38 c906b428-d5a5-4bd3-9c5e-202b52449dca.png
files:46 success`

Comment: that's after i uploaded 2 images.

Comment: you have teamviwer ? send user id pwd to vadiveljobs@gmail.com i see code

Comment: what values comes in "response" ?

Comment: hi, sorry i was a little away, i am currently on Linux, not teamviewer,  let me install it,

Comment: I sent you a mail, can you pls check?

Comment: are you online now ?

Comment: I fixed the issue, Thanks a lot.